# Rhino Mocks not throwing exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am trying to throw an exception from a test, (using rhino and nunit), but it is not working as expected

Interfaces

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body);
}

public interface IWebService
{
    void LogError(string message);
}
```

Classes

```
public class MockService : IWebService
{
    public string LastError;

    public void LogError(string message)
    {
        LastError = message;
    }
}

public class LogAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail
{
    public  IWebService Service { get; set; }
    public IEmailService Email { get; set; }

    public void Analyze(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileName.Length < 8)
                Service.LogError("Filename too short:" + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Email.SendEmail("a", "subject", exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test method

```
[Test]
    public void Analyze_WebServiceThrows_SendsEmail()
    {
        var mockRepository = new MockRepository();
        var stubWebService = mockRepository.Stub<IWebService>();
        var mockEmailService = mockRepository.StrictMock<IEmailService>();

        var logAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail = new LogAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail
        {
            Service = stubWebService,
            Email = mockEmailService
        };

        stubWebService.Stub(m => m.LogError("whatever")).IgnoreArguments().Throw(new Exception("fake exception"));


        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => { logAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail.Analyze("abc.ext"); });
        mockEmailService.AssertWasCalled(m => m.SendEmail("a", "subject", "fake exception"));

    }
```

But the test fails, and the message is "`Expected: <system.exception>, but was: null`"

Can anyone help me point out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your mock wasn't throwing an exception, but I'd recommend the newer RhinoMock syntax (no need to instantiate a MockRepository.) Also, your Assert.Throws call will not work, as your code is catching the exception.  Assert.Throws is only useful if the exception is uncaught.

Here's a working example.  Note that I moved the SendEmail expectation above your Analyze call. Regardless of the number of expectations on a mock, calling VerifyAllExpectations will make sure they were met.

```
[Test]
public void Analyze_WebServiceThrows_SendsEmail_Modified()
{
    var stubWebService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWebService>();
    var mockEmailService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEmailService>();

    var logAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail = new LogAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail
    {
        Service = stubWebService,
        Email = mockEmailService
    };

    // Set up our expectations
    stubWebService.Expect(m => m.LogError("whatever")).IgnoreArguments().Throw(new Exception("fake exception"));
    mockEmailService.Expect(m => m.SendEmail("a", "subject", "fake exception")).Repeat.Once();

    logAnalyzerDynamicMockWithEmail.Analyze("abc.ext");

    // Verify our SendEmail method was called
    mockEmailService.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Analyze()` method is catching the Exception and not rethrowing it, so it is never makes it's way back to the `Assert.Thows()` call.

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Email.SendEmail("a", "subject", exception.Message);
}
```

So your test is correctly failing.  The call to `Analyze()` does *not* throw an exception. Instead, it catches the exception thrown by your mock, sends an email and continues on.  If you want it to throw, you need to rethrow the exception in your `catch` block like this:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
     Email.SendEmail("a", "subject", exception.Message);
     throw;
}
```